# Packery miscalculated position because of jquery height

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, packery

I have a layout like the following image that I am using Packery to get. I am calculating the height of tall div with jquery too.

[image]

Everything is fine *on the second load, or when you refresh the page*. On the first load, the height of the tall div is not calculated and so packery positions my images on top of each other (in chrome). In firefox, a weird blank space is created and the elements are positioned around that space. I am not sure how to solve that.

My JS (Modified as suggested):

```
angular.module('BApp')
    .controller('HomeController', function($scope, $location) {
        function bannerResize() {
            var elmnt1 = $("#second").outerHeight();
            var elmnt2 = $("#third").outerHeight();
            var result = (elmnt1 + elmnt1) + 10;
            $("#tall .banner").css("height", result + 'px');
        }
        $(window).load(function(){
            bannerResize();
            var $container = $('.packery');
               $container.packery({
                "itemSelector": ".block"
            }) ;
        })
        })
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="row packery">

<div id="tall" class="block col-xs-12 tall" >
    <a href="#">
        <div class="banner">
            <img src="/images/banner/long.jpg">
            <div class="title"><h3><span>New</span></h3></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="second" class="block col-xs-12">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="banner">
            <img src="/images/banner/funny.jpg">
            <div class="title">
                <h3><span>Funny Clips</span></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="third" class="col-xs-12 block">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="banner">
            <img src="/images/banner/moviesongs.jpg">
            <div class="title">
                <h3><span>Movie Songs</span></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-24 block">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="banner">
            <img src="/images/banner/music.jpg">
            <div class="title">
                <h3><span>Music Videos</span></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 block">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="banner">
            <img src="/images/banner/sqr.jpg">
            <div class="title">
                <h3><span>Full Movie</span></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 block">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="banner">
            <img src="/images/banner/originals.jpg">
            <div class="title">
                <h3><span>Originals</span></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
     </a>
</div>

</div><!-- end .packery -->
```

I'm using bootstrap for the grid and using angular.js. The grids work fine if I don't size the `#tall` div and let it be, but obviously I can't do that, because it needs to be equal to the next two siblings' height. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Height is not calculated until all your HTML components are loaded. Try calling your function on:

```
$(window).load(function(){ /*code*/ });
```

That ensures you're grabbing the height when all your stuff is in the DOM. If you get some snapping action that you don't want, set your main div to opacity:0; and then add $('#main').css('opacity', 1) to the top of your window.load function, so that the page is blank until all the math is done.

Comment: I've modified the code as you suggested (see in my question, I updated), but now the height and packery positioned are not calculated at all on first load! On refresh, everything is fine. Is my syntax off( I'm not really great at jquery)?